# How to calculate sum on a row in AngularJS without triggering digest cycle?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of objects which are each represented by a row in a table.  One of the object values is "amount".  So the array looks something like this:

```
var array = [{name: 'bob', amount: 10}, {name: 'james', amount: 12});
```

At the top of the table, I have a function calculate the sum of all the amounts and print it there.  Unfortunately, it looks like this function is running every time some value is changing on the page even if it has nothing to do with that array.  Is there any way to make the function called only when the array is updated?

Comment: Expressions are evaluated during every digest cycle. If you want to avoid recalculating the sum for every digest cycle, then you should store the sum in a variable and update the variable when things change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could watch the values of interest in your controller and only then calculate the sum and update it as a separate value on your scope.

Alternatively, as a perhaps easier optimisation, you can consider debouncing the calculation. This would greatly reduce how often it is being re-calculated.

Comment: ah like set an ng-change on the values changing and then update the values

Comment: Hmm not exactly. More like keeping a new value on scope, say scope.sum which is your new sum shown in your view and then `$scope.$watch(array, (changedArray) => {sum = _. sumBy(changedArray, 'amount')})` (using lodash to sum amounts). This way sum is updated only on changes of the array. May need `$scope.applyAsync()` after the sum calculation to make it trigger a digest cycle to update the view.